# Bound combobox items refers to different field items

Tags: database, vb.net, combobox, items, multivalue

I got a bounded combobox to a group name in vb.net. i can view in the drop down items of the combobox the set of GROUP NAMES. but when i do an insert or update query, i need to make the selected group name refers to the GROUP NUMBER. I don't want to store letters in the database, instead i prefer numbers. how can i do that?!

Here is my code so far :

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@group", DirectCast(Additemcombobox.SelectedItem, 
                                  DataRowView).Item("GroupName"))
```

Storing the group name in database is currently working well.

My question might not be well explained. Please ask me in case...
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there a number associated with the names in the table it is bound to?  And what is it bound to exactly, a DataTable?

Comment: yes i got a table with 2 fields: group number and group name

Comment: the combobox is bounded to groupname; i want when i select the groupname to use its groupnumber inside my insert query

Comment: I know what you want.  ***what is it bound to exactly, a DataTable?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show one element to the user such as the name, but use a different one for the code to identify the item using `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`

```
Dim SQL = "SELECT Id, Name FROM GroupCode ORDER BY Name"
... 
GrpDT = New DataTable
GrpDT.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

cboGroup.DataSource = GrpDT
cboGroup.DisplayMember = "Name"
cboGroup.ValueMember = "Id"
```

The user will only see the names, while the code can use `ValueMember`:

```
Private Sub cboGroup_SelectedValueChanged(...etc
    Console.WriteLine(cboGroup.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

It prints the Group ID not the name.  Depending on the ORDER BY clause in the SQL and the ID, the `SelectedIndex` may or may not match, so respond to `SelectedValueChanged` event.  If you use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem` you wont have to thrash about with a `DataRowView` item.

Note that `SelectedValue` is `Object` so you will have to cast to integer or whatever for use elsewhere.

Comment: well thanks :D but one more thing, how could then in my datagrid see the groupname instead of the groupnumber when moving through my items. knowing that now it is all saved in numbers?

Comment: It depends on if that column is readonly.  It too could be a Combo or use the cellformatting event or a CustomFormatter.  Since you can now upvote, please do so, then upvote any Q or A you see which informs or helps.  It helps others find good answers